# Escape quotes in C for SQL

Tags: sql, c, string, escaping

I know it is bad practice to create SQL queries with strings and not use the Command class. But I am using a [third party tool](https://github.com/mobigroup/sqlite3-dbf) to convert dbf databases into sqlite databases and this tool doesn't escape single quotes in strings properly for the insert statement.
The tool produces this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO sample VALUES('1','Am G'haubach');
```

But correct would be that - note the double quote:

```
INSERT INTO sample VALUES('1','Am G''haubach');
```

Since the tool is on Github, I tried to fix the error myself, but I don't know anything about C and how to solve the problem:
Here is the part which escapes the values for the insert statement:

```
    /* Re-write invalid characters to their SQL-safe alternatives */
t = targetbuf;
for(s = buf; s <= lastchar; s++) {
switch(*s) {
case '\'':
    /* *t++ = '\\'; */
    *t++ = '\'\'';
    break;
case '\\':
    *t++ = '\\';
    *t++ = '\\';
    break;
case '\n':
    *t++ = '\\';
    *t++ = 'n';
    break;
case '\r':
    *t++ = '\\';
    *t++ = 'r';
    break;
case '\t':
    *t++ = '\\';
    *t++ = 't';
    break;
default:
    *t++ = *s;
}
}
```

The first case block is my attempt to fix the problem, but it didn't work. How do I correctly replace this single quote by two single quotes?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards
Nils

Comment: Look at how the code turns a single backslash into two backslashes and replicate it for single quotes

Comment: What you should do is to file a bug report.

Comment: @ChrisTurner thanks dude, your comment actually solved the problem for me, but since Paul created the answer even before I had tested it, I couldn't tell you to post it as answer. Thanks again. ;)

Comment: @Klutt even though your comment seemed to be a little sarcastic, I just realised that there was a pull request on github which fixed exactly my issue. :D

Comment: @Abenil It was not meant to be sarcastic at all. If you find a bug, the developers are more than happy to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are at the right place to fix it but it should be:

```
case '\'':
    *t++ = '\'';    // replace a single quote..
    *t++ = '\'';    //..with two single quotes
    break;
```

This assumes you are processing a variable in the sql statement so input is `Am G'haubach` and output is `Am G''haubach` which then still must be printed into the SQL statement with the single quotes surrounding it as `'Am G''haubach'`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for. ;) Chris Turner sent me on the right track, but I wasn't even able to try it before you posted your answer. Thumbs up! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally one should use placeholders in SQL for strings, so - as klutt suggested above - maybe the best thing to do is file a bug report. Nonetheless, if you are "in a jam", you could try the following. While traversing the input buffer, it examines adjacent characters as well as counts the number of quotes already parsed in order to estimate if it is in a string context.

```
int n_quotes = 0;
// Point to base of target buf ...
t = targetbuf;
while (*s) {
    switch (*s) {
        case '\'':
            // Examine the next character in an attempt
            // to determine if this is a 'string context'
            if (*(s + 1) != ',' && *(s + 1) != ')' && n_quotes % 2 == 1) {
                // We are more than likely inside a string ...
                *(t++) = '\'';
                *(t++) = '\'';
            } else {
                *(t++) = *s;
                n_quotes++;
            }
            break;
        default:
            *(t++) = *s;
            break;
    }
    s++;
}
*t = '\0';
puts(targetbuf);
```

Full example at http://codepad.org/XslS1XIf .

Output:

```
INSERT INTO sample VALUES('1', 'Am G''haubach');
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, I stripped pretty much information from my example because I thought it's not relevant. At the part I quoted, it's sure you are in a string context, since all the other data types will be handled by another function.